# scraper returning empty when trying to scrape in beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi so i want to scrape domain names and their prices but its returning null idk why

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.brandbucket.com/styles/6-letter-domain-names?page=1'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
names = soup.findAll('div', {'class': "domainCardDetail"})
print(names)
```

Comment: If you print the response, you'll see it says something about a Cloudflare CAPTCHA. You could use something like Selenium or [cloudscraper](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper) to try and bypass it.

Comment: You should use playwright iphone webdriver because this website is protected by cloudflare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach to get domain names and their price from that site. The script currently parses content from the first page only. If you wish to get content from other pages, make sure to use the desired page number here  ***`page=1`*** which is located within `link`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.brandbucket.com/styles/6-letter-domain-names?page=1'

url = 'https://www.brandbucket.com/amp/ga'

payload = {
    '__amp_source_origin': 'https://www.brandbucket.com'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
    payload['dp'] = soup.select_one("amp-iframe")['src'].split("list=")[1].split("&")[0]
    resp = s.get(url,params=payload)
    for key,val in resp.json()['triggers'].items():
        if not key.startswith('domain'):continue
        container = val['extraUrlParams']
        print(container['pr1nm'],container['pr1pr'])
```

Output are like (truncated):

```
estita.com 2035
rendro.com 1675
rocamo.com 3115
wzrdry.com 4315
prutti.com 2395
bymodo.com 3495
ethlax.com 2035
intezi.com 2035
podoxa.com 2430
rorror.com 3190
zemoxa.com 2195
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the status code of the response. When I tested there was 403 from the Web Server and because of that there is no such element like "domainCardDetail" div in response.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that website is protected by Cloudflare.
There are some advanced ways to bypass this.

The following solution is very simple if you do not need a mass amount of scraping. Otherwise, you may want to use "clouscraper" "Selenium" or another method to enable JavaScript on the website.

1. Open the developer console
2. Go to "Network". Make sure ticks are clicked as below picture.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0KTv.png
3. Refresh the page.
4. Copy JSON result and parse it in Python
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/odX5S.png

Comment: thanks man i got the json result you said but where do i put it in? i'm really noob thanks again

Comment: You can treat this as a Python dictionary and parse the information you need.

Comment: hey man in this <a class="toggle-fav toggle-fav-thumbnail-icon" data-domain="huglo.com" data-price="3092" href="#" title="Favourite"> i only want data-domain and data-price what should i do? this is the code    titles = soup.find_all("a", class_="toggle-fav toggle-fav-thumbnail-icon")

Comment: In the solution, I provided you do not need to use soup selectors. You can just copy and paste response and access values using dictionary keys.

Comment: yeah bro i got that but that query is from another website i almost got it but don't know how to print the data-domain and data-price within class. really appreciate your help tho